# Redirect with dynamic parameters .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

There is a dynamic parameter in urls `s=changingtext`. It is necessary to recognize this parameter and add another parameter to it for redirecting to get `s=changingtext&post_type=product`.

There is a link for example

```
example.com/?min_price=0&max_price=0&s=test
```

it should always redirect to

```
example.com/?min_price=0&max_price=0&s=test&post_type=product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the order of the URL parameters is not significant then you can do it like this using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)s=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?post_type=product [QSA,R=302,L]
```

This adds the `post_type` URL parameter first and the existing query string is appended using the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag. ie. In your example, it will be redirected to `example.com/?post_type=product&min_price=0&max_price=0&s=test`.

This specifically checks for a non-empty `s` URL parameter. An empty URL parameter, eg. `foo=1&s=&bar=1` will not be redirected.

This applies to any URL-path.